# iOS - Using a custom toolbar / navigation bar that remains stationary for all UIViewController transitions?

Tags: ios, static, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, uitoolbar

I want to use a customized toolbar/navigation bar at the top of my app window that should remain stationary during all uiviewcontroller transitions.

Basically a global toolbar with buttons, labels, etc. that remain completely static and doesn't move around when pushing/popping other view controllers. This toolbar should have a form of delegate methods so that I can have buttons on it that are usable on all view controllers.

I am developing using the XCode 5.1.1 for an iOS 7.0+ iPad-only app.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you have any ideas?

Comment: Was looking into using container views embedded in a navigation controller, but haven't used them before so not sure how that would work (if at all).

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own container view controller, which has one child. Use a navigation controller as the child and `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`, then act as the delegate of the navigation controller so you know when the current view changes.

For your 'global' buttons, have the container view controller as the target of the buttons. When a button is tapped the container forwards it to the top view controller in the nav controller stack. To enable this all of your view controllers can conform to a protocol which specifies the methods related to the buttons (this is a nicety for the compiler, you can just that the view controller responds to the required method).